# PHP Show 2nd foreach in td next to the first loop's values

Tags: php, html, sqlite, html-table

I have a SQLite- file with values. 
I get those values and display them in a table of 2 columns:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO("sqlite:$dbPath");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Object;');
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

<table id="table1">
  <caption><em>caption</em></caption>

   <?php foreach($res as $objekt):
  $imageFile = basename($objekt['image']); ?>

   <tr>

    <td><?php if(isset($objekt['image'])): ?>
      <figure class="objectPicture center">
        <img src="img/bmo/250/<?php echo $imageFile;?>" alt="<?php echo $objekt['title'];?>">
        <?php else: ?>no picture.<?php endif ?><br>
        <figcaption><?php echo $objekt['title']; ?>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </td>

    <td><?php echo $objekt['text']; ?><br>
    <?php echo $objekt['owner']; ?></td>
  </tr>

  <?php endforeach; ?>

  </table>
```

What I'd like to do is to show the next foreach-loop (values of row2 in the SQLite- file) in another 2 columns next to the first result. And the 3rd loop under the first one and so on.

How do I do that? (total newbie to PHP and SQL here, in case you didn't notice)

The results now:
[image: current results]

What I want:
[image: what I want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 Changes to make

1. Add `$idx` to foreach loop

> ```
> <?php foreach($res as $idx => $objekt):
> ```

2. Wrap `if` around `<tr>`

> ```
> <?php if($idx % 2 == 0) { ?>
>    <tr>
> <?php } ?>
> ```

3. Wrap `if` around `</tr>`

> ```
> <?php if($idx % 2 == 1) { ?>
>    </tr>
> <?php } ?>
> ```

**The above code doesn't consider the case when row number is odd**

Comment: I got another Q about this solution: I don't really get how it works, I tried removing the table alltogether and use this code with divs instead of td and tr and tried to change it to show 3 "columns" (tried 3 == 0 3==1 3==2 and so on, but it didn't work) How would I do that?